# Validación desactivar checkbox no funciona

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tardes hay alguien que me pueda ayudar con mi siguiente duda.
Tengo el siguiente código en HTML.

```
MATERIAL O RESIDUO PELIGROSO: 
<label style="margin-left: 10px;">SI</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="disableCheckbox2()">
<label style="margin-left: 10px;">NO</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="disableCheckbox1()">
```

Necesito que al dar clic en SI o NO se deshabilité el otro checkbox.

El siguiente código es en JS para checar si esta seleccionado cualquier de los 2 checkbox.

Intente usar esas 2 el .Checked y el .is(':checked') pero en el primero siempre entra al else y el segundo dice que el .is no es una función.

```
function disableCheckbox2() {
            if(document.getElementById("myCheck").Checked == true)
            {
                document.getElementById("myCheck2").disabled = true;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("myCheck2").disabled = false;
            }
        }
        function disableCheckbox1() {
            if(document.getElementById("myCheck2").is(':checked') == true)
            {
                document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = true;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = false;
            }
        }
```

Les pido su ayuda y de antemano gracias

Comment: puedes usar `<input type="radio" />` si quieres que el usuario solo pueda seleccionar una opción

Comment: En ambos casos debes usar `document.getElementById("id_del_checkbox").checked`, con `checked` en minúsculas y sin la función `.is()`

Comment: Gracias a los 2 utilice la segunda opción del ```document.getElementById("").checked``` para no modificar los campos.